# Delete dupplicate with the lowest id

Tags: php

I've been trying this by splitting the lines with sub-string and than using array unique on it but I can't get it to work properly. The idea is, if the same line is in the file with a lower number, keep the line with the higher number.

Textfile:

```
wood    tiger    22324    Squirrel
john    apple    24574    Squirrel                                  
peter   snuggle  21234    Squirrel                                  
james   coolest  20108    Squirrel                                  
james   coolest  20134    Squirrel
```

Output needed:

```
wood    tiger    22324    Squirrel  
john    apple    24574    Squirrel                                  
peter   snuggle  21234    Squirrel                                  
james   coolest  20134    Squirrel
```

So, basically it has to keep the highest numbered item if it's in the same line (the higher the number the newer the line is).

What I've tried so far:

```
$file_handle = fopen("file.txt", "rb" , FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);


while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    if ($line_of_text[0] === ' ') continue;  
        if ($line_of_text[0] === ' ') continue;  

    $part1 = substr("$line_of_text", ..., ...); 
    $part2 = substr("$line_of_text", ..., ...);
    $part3 = substr("$line_of_text", ..., ...);
    $part1 = explode(' ', $part1);
    $part1 = array_unique($part1);
    $part1 = implode(' ', $part1);      
var_dump ($part1);
}       

file_put_contents('outputfile.txt', implode(PHP_EOL, $lines));

?>
```

Comment: what is the output? what is the error?

Comment: http://blog.geneticcoder.com/2015/05/04/removing-duplicate-rows-from-a-2-dimensional-associative-array/

Comment: pamblam, what does that have to do with the question? how should I use it?

Comment: The answer to your question is inside the posted page and the linked page https://3v4l.org/mXZEI you only have to read the article ;-)

Comment: clearly does not keep the highest number :D or do I overlook?

Comment: Do you only care if the first column is repeated? What if you had another row that started with `james snuggle`?

Comment: nothing because it has to check the complete line and keep the duplicate one with the highest number.